# How Can I Make a Redirect Page in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, redirect

I want to build a page that displays html for a short while and then redirects the user to another URL without opening a new window. How can this be done quickly in Jquery?

Comment: you don't need jQuery for everything...just do `setTimeout(function(){window.location='something.html';},5000)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't need javascript, just add the meta tag in the head:

```
// for 5 seconds
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.example.com/" />
```

Comment: Awesome! This is great!

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = "your link";
        }, 5000);
    };
</script>
```

After 5 second, it will redirect.
replace"your link" with the link you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not wanting to open the URL in a new window use window.location.href = xx

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
},5000);// after 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// you can use jquery document ready function to call your code after DOM ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.open('your url to open');
    },5000);// after 5 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function() {
   window.location = "new url";
}, 5000);
```